# changing element inside uitableview row affects other row on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to change Uimage color inside my uitableview row bases on item

list array. for example if the have record id equal to one of number inside

my array the color will be changed. this is my code :

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", _ID_list_entries];
        BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:appRecord.ids];

        if(result)
        {
           UIButton *B_btn = (UIButton *)[sctvCell.contentView viewWithTag:504];
NSLog(@"self.ID_list_entries appRecord.ids : %@",appRecord.ids);
            CGSize targetSize = (CGSize){100,100};
            UIImage* image;
            {
                CGRect rect_2 = (CGRect){ .size = targetSize };

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( targetSize );
                {
                    CGContextRef X = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

                    UIImage* uiGem = [UIImage imageNamed: @"graycolor_btn.png"];

                    // draw gem
                    [uiGem drawInRect: rect_2];

                    // overlay a red rectangle
                    CGContextSetBlendMode( X, kCGBlendModeColor ) ;
                    CGContextSetRGBFillColor ( X,  0.9, 0, 0,  1 );
                    CGContextFillRect ( X, rect_2 );

                    // redraw gem
                    [uiGem drawInRect: rect_2
                            blendMode: kCGBlendModeDestinationIn
                                alpha: 1. ];

                    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                }
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            }


            [B_btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
```

now the problem is this also change other rows when i scroll.

im using this method inside my :

```
- (void)configureCellXXX:(UITableViewCell *)sctvCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

also in my log there are one

```
self.ID_list_entries appRecord.ids : 102
```

each time im scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because the tableview is reusing that cell. You need to reset it by overriding the `prepareForReuse` method in your custom cell and resetting the value to what you want to be default.

Comment: thanks for answer , can u show how can i achive this ? im subclassing my cell

Comment: From what I can tell from your code, it would be something like `-(void)prepareForReuse{ [self.button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal]; }` in your cell subclass.